# A word for "being worked on"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Are there any adjectives meaning *"being worked on"* or *"being in progress or development"*?
I need an intermediate step between "open" and "close" (talking about the process of fixing a software bug or implementing an application feature).

Thanks.

Comment: It's just possible that 'address' has a middle usage meaning 'be addressed', though I can't find the intransitive sense in any dictionary. If OED has it, 'addressing' would qualify.

Comment: You can say it is "In-Progress" (Example from [Rally](https://www.rallydev.com/) agile software I happen to be using).

Comment: It would help to know your objective... Are you manufacturing software bugs, identifying them, or eliminating them?  If it's the latter, why not use a word for "bugs" - "exterminating"?

Comment: @Oldbag No, I'm not manufacturing code bugs :D. I've edited the question to be more clear. Thanks though.

Comment: Show your target sentence.

Comment: By usual definitions in the computer biz, an "open" bug is one that's been documented but not yet marked "fixed".  ("Closed" occurs when the fix has been tested and certified correct.)  There may be another step involving examining the bug report and assigning it to an investigator/developer, after which the bug would be "accepted" or "assigned".  It really depends on your process.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, maybe "new", "assigned", "active", "closed"...

Comment: [WIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_in_process) : *work in process*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'In Progress' is commonly used. If you want a one-word answer, try:

**Underway**

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/underway):

> Having started and in progress; being done or carried out:

Answer (score 1):

I would say "still in the works" or "in the works". Don't know if that is professional or not, but everyone understands it!

Comment: “Still in the works” is not quite an adjective ;)

Answer (score 0):

The word, "processing" might work.

Comment: I don't like it much. It's more often used as "the act of processing" or as "being the one who/which processes" (eg. _"processing unit"_)